# For which values of $x$, will $f (x) . f '(x) < 0$?

Tags: calculus, functions

Give $f (x) = x^3 - 4x^2 - 3x + 18$

For which values of $x$, will $f (x) . f'(x) < 0$?

And also, how can I understand these type of questions? I always get stuck on them.
Other examples are:

$$\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} > 0$$
$$xf (x) > 0$$

Comment: Compute $f'(x)$ using the differentiation rules, then solve the inequality $f'(x) < 0$ for $x$. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @EthanAlwaise it is $f(x)\cdot f^\prime(x)$, so a polynomial of degree 5. Brute-force approaches can get ugly.

Comment: @Ethan Alwaise ...At school we're taught to read the answer of the graph and not do any calculating. How do you do that?

Comment: Graphing calculators will find you the zeroes of $f(x)f'(x)$, and so you just take the appropriate intervals.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$f(x)=x^3-4x^2-3x+18=(x-3)^2(x+2)$$

and

$$f'(x)=3x^2-8x-3=(x-3)(3x+1)$$

Therefore, we have

$$f(x)f'(x)=(x-3)^3(x+2)(3x+1)$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: Yes... what about (f (x)/f'(x)) > 0 and x.f (x) > 0?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a product of things and want it to be negative, an odd number of those things must be negative and none of them can be zero.  It is similar for a ratio as $\frac 1x \gt 0$ exactly when $x \gt 0$.

In your specific question, you should compute $f'(x)$ and find the roots of both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.  These are the points where intervals of the product being negative can end.  The roots of $f(x)=0$ and $f'(x)=0$ yield to the rational root theorem, so they are not hard to find.  One of the roots of $f(x)=0$ is double, so there is no sign change there.

Answer (score 0):

1) This value $f(x)*f'(x)$ is going to be less than $0$ when either $f(x)<0$ OR(exclusively) $f'(x)<0$.

2) $f'(x) = 0$ is precisely the local maximums and minimums of $f(x)$

3) $f"(x) = 0$ will be the local maximums and minimums of $f'(x)$

4) Recall Descarte's Rule of Signs

Answer (score 0):

Take derivative

$$y'={3x^2-8x-3}$$

Factor and Solve

f'[x]<0

You Should get (-1/3, 3) are all values of x