# for what values of x will f (x).f'(x) < 0

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Given f (x) = x^3 - 4x^2 - 3x + 18

For which values of x will:
f (x) . f'(x) < 0

How would you read the answer straight of the graph without any calculations?
The answers should be in this form:
Example, (3 > x > 7) (NOT THE CORRECT ANSWER TO MY PROBLEM)

Comment: Which parts in particular are you struggling with?

Comment: For which values of x will will f (x).f'(x) < 0

Comment: No. I know how to do it but I'd like to know how to read the answer straight off the graph

Comment: I have to ask *why* you want to read the answer straight off the graph...

Comment: Something like [your previous, identical question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657744/for-which-values-of-x-will-f-x-f-x-0), maybe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a duplicate of a question already posted by the OP.

Comment: We're taught in class to read it straight off the graph

Comment: @myv Then observe that $f^\prime \cdot f$ is negative exactly when $2f^\prime f$ is negative, and that the latter is the derivative of $f^2$. So graph $f^2$, and see where it is decreasing. But you shouldn't have posted a new question: instead, editing your previous one would have done the job.)

Comment: Ok thanks. And sorry, i'm just new here.

Comment: This is a slightly different question as the OP wants to view the answers solely be looking at a graph.  Not by calculating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x) * f'(x) < 0$ either $f(x)$ is positive and $f'(x)$ is negative or vice versa.

I can see if $f(x) > 0$ by seeing if the graph at x is a above or below the x-axis.  I can see if $f'(x) > 0$ by seeing if at x the graph is increasing or not.

So I look for the areas of the graph with it is either both above the x-axis and decreasing or below the x-axis and increasing.

Comment: Sorry i'm still confused. What will the answer be? Do you only look at the x values?

Comment: Huh???  You look at the *graph*.  The shape of the curve.  There are sections where the graph is above the x axis.  Those are where f(x) > 0.  (Duh!).  And there are sections where the graph is below the x-axis.  Those are where f(x) < 0. (Again, Duh!)  And you will see sections where the graph is increasing.  (Duh!) Those are where f'(x) > 0 (Duh!) and you will see sections where the graph is decreasing. (Duh)  Thare are where f'(x) < 0.  (duh!)  So there are four things the graph can be doing.... to be continued...

Comment: It can be at or above the x-axis and be flat or  increasing.  Then $f(x) \ge 0$ and $f'(x) \ge 0$ so $f(x)f'(x) \ge 0$.  We don't want those areas.  It can be at or below the x-axis and be flat or decreasing.  Then $f(x) \le 0$ and $f'(x) \le 0$ so $f(x)f'(x) \ge 0$.  We don't want those areas either.  It can be above the x-axis and decreasing.  The f(x) > 0 and f'(x) < 0 and f(x)f'(x) < 0.  We want that section.  Or it con be below the x-axis and increasing.  So f(x) < 0 and f'(x) > 0 so f(x)f'(x) < 0.  We want that section too.